# function referencing inside sdf_pivot

Tags: r, sparklyr

all:

I am having trouble referencing simple functions inside sdf_pivot. Can anyone help? Thanks!

This is the code that works, but not exactly what I need:

```
spark_disconnect_all();
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client")
mtcars_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, mtcars, name = "mtcars_tbl", overwrite = TRUE)
mtcars_tbl %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(mpg > 30, "High", "Low" )) %>%
  sdf_pivot(mpg+cyl ~ gear, fun.aggregate = list(hp = "mean"))
```

I want to calculate mean with NA removed and median calculated as well, ideally with NA removed as well. I cannot get the following codes to work though:

```
mtcars_tbl %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(mpg > 30, "High", "Low" )) %>% 
  sdf_pivot(mpg+cyl ~ gear, fun.aggregate = list(hp = "mean(na.rm=TRUE)")) 
mtcars_tbl %>%
  mutate(mpg = ifelse(mpg > 30, "High", "Low" )) %>%
  sdf_pivot(mpg+cyl ~ gear, fun.aggregate = list(hp = "percentile(0.5)"))
```

This is the result I need:

```
  mpg     cyl `3.0` `4.0` `5.0`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Low       8  194.  NaN   300.
2 High      4  NaN    61   113 
3 Low       4   97    85    91 
4 Low       6  108.  116.  175
```

My data is 800 million rows and I'm just using a single example here for the purpose of easy replication. In reality, I cannot just collect it to a dataframe in R. All the calculation has to be on spark. A lot of things stop to work on Spark, median function is one. I can get percentile function to work but not median. But I can't figure out how to supply the extra parameters in this specific setting.

Comment: Please don't ask your questions inside your source code as comments. For improved readability split your code and ask precise question outside your code.

Comment: I have edited per your suggestion. Thanks.